# Spring/Hibernate Multitenancy - LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy error

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, multi-tenant

I'm building a multitenant application and used this as a source of reference: https://www.baeldung.com/multitenancy-with-spring-data-jpa. Although most of the DB calls work fine, some are exhibiting confusing behavior. Here is an example:

The following class `MultiTenantConfiguration`provides all the necessary beans for configuring the datasource, sessions and transactions:

```
 class MultiTenantConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
       AbstractRoutingDataSource dataSource = new RoutingDataSource();
       dataSource.setTargetDataSources(....);
       dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(....);
       dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
       
       return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        builder.scanPackages("....");
        return builder.buildSessionFactory();
    }   

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }

}
```

The following class provides the `id` of DB source to lookup:

```
class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return TENANT_CONTEXT.getCurrentTenant();
    }

}
```

This is the API service which calls the internal user service:

```
class UserAPIResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/api/users_0/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getUser0(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return userService.getUserForId_0(id);
    }   

    @GET
    @Path("/api/users_1/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getUser1(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return userService.getUserForId_1(id);
    }   

    @GET
    @Path("/api/users_2/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getUser2(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return userService.getUserForId_2(id);
    }

}
```

This is the  `UserService` that communicates with the JPA repo - `UserRepository`, converts it into a  consumable POJO and returns:

```
class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepo;


    public User getUserForId_0(Long id) {
        RawUser rawUser= userRepo.getById(id);
        User user =  new User();
        user.setId(rawUser.getId());
        user.setName(rawUser.getName());

        return user;
    }

    @Transactional
    public User getUserForId_1(Long id) {
        RawUser rawUser= userRepo.getById(id);
        User user =  new User();
        user.setId(rawUser.getId());
        user.setName(rawUser.getName());

        return user;
    }


    public User getUserForId_2(Long id) {
        RawUser rawUser= userRepo.findById(id);
        User user =  new User();
        user.setId(rawUser.getId());
        user.setName(rawUser.getName());

        return user;
    }

}
```

Here is the `RawUser` entity class. It does not have any mappings to other entities:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
class RawUser {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  public long getId() {return id;}

  public String getName() {return name;}
}
```

Now, `/api/users_0/1` throws: `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.db.model.User#1] - no Session`.

However, `/api/users_1/1` and `/api/users_2/1` return successfully.

The difference is that  `/api/users_1/1` which calls `userService.getUserForId_1()` is marked as `Transactional`.

And `/api/users_2/1` which calls `userService.getUserForId_1()` uses `findById()` instead of `getById()`.

This behavior only happens in the multi-tenant structure. So I'm guessing I'm missing  some additional configuration, specifically in Sessions/Proxy? If someone can explain this, that'd be great.

Comment: How is you problem related to multitenancy? `getById` call returns proxy object, it cannot be fully initialized "outside transaction"/"without session", `findById` call returns entity.

Comment: This doesn't happen in a non-multitenant  setup. Yes, I'm thinking I'm missing some session/transaction configuration in the multi-tenant setup.

Comment: @user2354302 were you able to resolve it? iam also facing similar issue